# django-registration with django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms, django-registration

Can anybody please point to a working example of Django-Registration integrated with Django-CMS? I am having difficulties in doing so. What I could accomplish is...

- Successfully install django-cms
- Successfully install django-registration
- successfully created a cms_app.py ( I say this because the "Registration" app was available for hooking on the page)
- Hooked up the Registration app on the page through admin login.

What I couldn't get to work...

- Using of `{{ form.username }}` on the page ( the page is a custom page that resides in "templates" folder of my project ( not app))